# Como separar dados de uma coluna

Tags: r, table

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de separar os dados da primeira coluna em outras duas. Há um "." entre o nível de instrução e o setor. Tentei usar a função `separate` mas não deu certo.

Meu código:

```
pnad_2019_tratada %>% separate(interaction(VD3004, VD4010), c("instrucao", "setor"), ".")
```

Comment: Victor, evite usar imagens. Isso dificulta a reprodução, tente o comandou `dput()`

Answer (score 5):

O comando está correto, porém para usar o `.` como "referência para um padrão de texto", é necessário colocar como `\\.`

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Dados

```
df <-
  tibble(
    x = c("Sem instrução e menos de 1 ano de estudo.Agricultura",
          "Fundamental incompleto ou equivalente.Agricultura")
  )
```

### Código

Com o comando `separate` você pode criar novas colunas (`into`) a partir de uma coluna (`col`) e um separador (`sep`).

```
df %>% 
  separate(col = x, into = c("instrucao","setor"),sep = "\\.")
```

### Resultado

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  instrucao                                setor      
  <chr>                                    <chr>      
1 Sem instrução e menos de 1 ano de estudo Agricultura
2 Fundamental incompleto ou equivalente    Agricultura
```